# Visual Studio 2019 - Nodejs Typescript ignores build script in package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio, build

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to write Nodejs apps using Typescript and when I build the solution (or it's automatically built on run/debug), it uses the build script inside package.json to generate the Javascript files.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "npx tsc"
}
```

Now however, in any other new project I create, Visual Studio seems to ignore this build script and so the Javascript files are never generated, and I'm forced to manually run the compile command myself in an external terminal.

I've created test projects using identical package.json & tsconfig.json files and these also ignore the build script, so I assume it must be a setting within the project file its self.

I've looked everywhere and just can't seem to figure out why it's being ignored.
Any advice on this would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

**Edit**
After comparing .njsproj files, I found that `EnableTypeScript` was one of few differences and it was missing. Once I manually added it, Visual Studio now uses the build script defined inside package.json.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   ...
   <Name> abc </Name>
   <RootNamespace> abc </RootNamespace>
   <EnableTypeScript>true</EnableTypeScript>
   <SaveNodeJsSettingsInProjectFile>True</SaveNodeJsSettingsInProjectFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But how is this changed or automatically added without manual modifications?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to run one script when in Debug config and another when in Release config.